Wi-Fi, рабочая/гостевая сеть
Ситуация следующая - у меня стоит роутер( в режиме Ретранслятор) и разумеется есть рабочая и гостевая сеть. С рабочей сетью всё ок. С гостевой сетью проблема - я ввёл ssid и пароль, vlan, dchp вкл, но к ней не подключается устройства, пишет что ошибка подключения при этом wi-fi гостевой он излучает( я смотрел в списке подключенных устройств, там все только на рабочей сети). Буду рад вашим советам.
Версия роутера Keenetic Hopper (KN-3810).
